# Javafx and repositioning an image upon window resize?

Tags: java, javafx, listener

Ok so I am trying to become familiar with adding listener's to objects and thought I would try and modify one of my applications to have it recenter an image after the pane was resized like it showed me in an example....which worked....only in this project when I try and perform the same thing I get this exception:

```
Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: MouseEvent.MouseEventDemo.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1773)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:119)
```

The code I used is here:

```
// Add a listener to relocate object upon pane resize
        pane.widthProperty().addListener(ov -> {
            circularText.relocate(pane.getWidth() / 2, pane.getHeight() / 2);
            imageView2.relocate(pane.getWidth() / 2, pane.getHeight() / 2);
        });

        pane.heightProperty().addListener(ov -> {
            circularText.relocate(pane.getWidth() / 2, pane.getHeight() / 2);
            imageView2.relocate(pane.getWidth() / 2, pane.getHeight() / 2);
        });
```

If you need the entire main, part of the code you can find it below:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.effect.BlendMode;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 * Created by John on 7/17/2014.
 */
class MouseEventDemo extends Application {
    private double rotateImage;
    private final Pane pane = new Pane();

    @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Set pane's properties
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black");

        // Create and add objects
        setMouseTrail();
        setCenterObject();

        // Create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setTitle("MouseTrailDemo"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
    }

    /** Set mouse trail */
    void setMouseTrail() {
        // Create image for cursor
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image("/image/anon5.jpg"));
        imageView.setBlendMode(BlendMode.SCREEN);
        imageView.setCache(true);
        pane.getChildren().add(imageView);

        // Create a new RotatingText object
        Font font = Font.font("Courier New", FontWeight.BOLD, 12);
        RotatingText circlePane = new RotatingText("We Are Anonymous",
                220, font);
        circlePane.setCircleSize(36);
        circlePane.setTextColor(Color.LIME);
        circlePane.relocate(imageView.getX() + 34,
                imageView.getY() + 29.55);
        pane.getChildren().add(circlePane);

        // Rotation transform for animation counter clockwise
        final Rotate rotationTransform = new Rotate(360, 0, 0);
        circlePane.getTransforms().add(rotationTransform);

        // Animate the RotatingText object
        Timeline rotatingText = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
                Duration.seconds(5),
                new KeyValue(rotationTransform.angleProperty(), 0)));
        rotatingText.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        rotatingText.play();

        // Set text to circle image and image to follow mouse
        pane.setOnMouseMoved(e -> {
            imageView.setX(e.getX() - 10);
            imageView.setY(e.getY() + 30);
            circlePane.relocate(imageView.getX() + 34,
                    imageView.getY() + 29.55);
        });
    }

    /** Set center object and animate it */
    void setCenterObject() {
        // Create circular text
        Font font2 = Font.font("Courier New", FontWeight.BOLD, 12);
        CircularText circularText = new CircularText("We Are Anonymous",
                325, 325);
        circularText.setTextFill(Color.LIME);
        circularText.setTextSize(12, 1.3, 1.1);
        circularText.setFont(font2);
        circularText.setTextRotate(90, 360);
        circularText.setGapSpacing(0.95);
        circularText.setTextStartDegree(360);
        circularText.relocate(300, 300);
        pane.getChildren().add(circularText);

        // Rotation transform for circular text animation and image
        final Rotate rotationTransform = new Rotate(360, 0, 0);
        circularText.getTransforms().add(rotationTransform);


        // Animate the RotatingText object
        Timeline rotatingText = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
                Duration.seconds(10),
                new KeyValue(rotationTransform.angleProperty(), 0)));
        rotatingText.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        rotatingText.play();

        // Load image for center
        ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(new Image("/image/anon3.jpg"));
        imageView2.setBlendMode(BlendMode.SCREEN);
        imageView2.setCache(true);
        imageView2.setX(circularText.getLayoutX() - 145);
        imageView2.setY(circularText.getLayoutY() - 125);
        pane.getChildren().add(imageView2);

        // Create EventHandler for image
        rotateImage = 0;
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> eventHandler = e -> {
            if (rotateImage == 360)
                rotateImage = 0;
            rotateImage += 1;
            imageView2.setRotate(rotateImage);
        };

        // Animate the image rotation
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
                Duration.millis(35), eventHandler));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();

        // Add a listener to relocate object upon pane resize
        pane.widthProperty().addListener(ov -> {
            circularText.relocate(pane.getWidth() / 2, pane.getHeight() / 2);
            imageView2.relocate(pane.getWidth() / 2, pane.getHeight() / 2);
        });

        pane.heightProperty().addListener(ov -> {
            circularText.relocate(pane.getWidth() / 2, pane.getHeight() / 2);
            imageView2.relocate(pane.getWidth() / 2, pane.getHeight() / 2);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That just looks like IntelliJ still wants you to include a `main(...)` method.

Comment: ahh...yeah strange, it only seems to do that when I add a listener

Comment: Ok so that's exactly what it was....but why would adding a listener to pane cause IntelliJ to require a main method?

Comment: I think it had something to do with 'avast!' it started acting strange right after downloading it! Can you believe that is the first time I have downloaded a virusscanner in about 2 years and low and behold the first time I do that on this machine I start having problems, never had this computer freeze up until I did this....After running my first scan everything went black except my status bar and then after shutting my laptop screen and opening everything came back....Well then it froze and I had to force a shutdown and it corrupted my workspace.xml file XD

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm an idiot apparently it wasn't because of the listener I added, it was because I had created a new project to place my files in and I selected the wrong type XD

Also I ended up having a problem opening my last project that it was contained in because upon installing avast! and running my first quickscan the virus-scanner locked my computer up causing me to force a shutdown and causing my workspace.xml file in the .idea to become corrupt...deleting it and reopening the project and re-running the program seemed to fix it